# Fluent NHibernate: load a fixed number of items from a collection

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Suppose I have an entity in Fluent NHibernate that looks like this:

```
 public class Feed
{
    public virtual int FeedId { get; set; }
    public virtual string FeedUri { get; set; }
    public virtual string FeedTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual string FeedHomePageUri { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<FeedItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm loading the Items collection on this entity, is there a way to tell my query engine to only load the first 10 items in the collection?

Suppose there are 10000 items in this collection - I only want to peek at the first 10. Is there a way to do this?

I know the collection is lazy loaded, and that's not what I'm asking. When I do pop the bubble and finally load everything, how do I stop it from querying all 10000 records when I only want the first 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't "half-load" a collection. When it's loaded, all the items are.

Now... what you CAN do is use [filters](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-filtering), which are just queries created on a collection.

Example:

```
var feed = session.Get<Feed>(feedId);
var first10Items = session.Filter(feed.Items, "")
                          .SetMaxResults(10)
                          .List<FeedItem>()
```

Comment: That looks like it should work - I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.